# How to handle divide by zero exception in pandas while using it in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dividebyzeroexception

where the value are 0 on which i'am doing division, which seems to throw an error. How to avoid this error

```
 wt     pred wt  remarks
  0      14      Anomaly
  0      20      Anomaly
  25     30      Anomaly
  22     21      Anomaly
  21     102     Anomaly


     def valuation_formula(x,y):
         if float(abs(x-y)/y*100) > 25.0:
            return "Anomaly"
         else :
            return "Pass"

     try:
        df_Wt['Weight_Remarks'] = df_Wt.apply(lambda row: 
        valuation_formula(row['Predicted Weight'], row['Weight']), axis=1)

     except ZeroDivisionError:
        df_Wt['Weight_Remarks'] = "Anomaly"
```

The new column is only filled with "Anomaly" how do i correct this above code

Expected output

```
            wt      pred wt  remarks
            0        14      Anomaly
            0        20      Anomaly
           25        30      Pass
           22        21      Pass
           21        102     Anomaly
```

Comment: can you put the expected output as table?

Comment: Are there supposed to be two different strings ("Anomaly" and "Weight Anomaly") or should they be the same?

Comment: they are same, i have updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['remarks'] = np.where(((abs(df['pred wt']-df['wt']))/df['wt']).gt(0.25), "Weight Anomaly", 'Pass')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np

df['new_remarks'] = np.where(df['wt'].ne(0), df['pred wt']/df['wt'], 'Anomaly')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   wt  pred wt  remarks         new_remarks
0   0       14  Anomaly             Anomaly
1   0       20  Anomaly             Anomaly
2  25       30  Anomaly                 1.2
3  22       21  Anomaly  0.9545454545454546
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a great idea having mixed types in a column

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
df['remarks']= np.where(df.wt.div(df.pred,fill_value=1).eq(0),'Anamoly',np.where(((abs(df['pred']-df['wt']))/df['wt']).lt(0.25), "Weight Anomaly", 'Pass'))
```

I think the output you have put does not match the function. At least one of the values should be 'Weight Anamoly'. Tweak `lt(0.25)` to get the result you want. lt stands for 'less than', you can change that to 'gt' (greater than) to suit your needs

Comment: Are you sure? you have 3 conditions. When number is indivisible, it should be 'Anamoly', when it is divisible but less than 0.25, then 'Weight Anamoly' & if the division is above 0.25, then 'Pass'. The previous answer had only 2 conditions. It is up-to you as to which one you use.